# Subtract constant value from each band in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

[Go through the sample code here from GEE](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d6f3ca4af9956c99cc22f85d62850ec2)

Here I tried to subtract mean value of a band from the same band. Likewise I wanted to do it for generating a Z score image which is (x-mean/sigma)
Idea is to identify the outliers in the given image/band using z-score. Are there any better solutions available for outlier identification in GEE?

```
// Load a Landsat 8 image.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1/LC08_044034_20140318');

Map.addLayer(image.select(["B10"]), {}, 'selected band');

// Combine the mean and standard deviation reducers.
var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  sharedInputs: true
});

// Use the combined reducer to get the mean and SD of the image.
var stats = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: reducers,
  bestEffort: true,
});

// Display the dictionary of band means and SDs.
print((stats.select(["B10_stdDev"])));
var subtract1 = (image.select(["B10"]).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  bestEffort: true,
}))

print(subtract1.get("B10"))
var substract = image.select(["B10"]).subtract(subtract1.get("B10"))

Map.addLayer(substract, {}, 'substracted image');
```

> ERROR
> substracted image: Layer error: Image.subtract, argument 'image2': Invalid type.
> Expected type: Image.
> Actual type: Float.
> Actual value: 24825.60147454021

Comment: got the solution by replacing
`var number = ee.Number(subtract1.get("B10"))`

`var substract = image.select(["B10"]).subtract(number)`

Comment: please post this as answer with proper explanation how it worked. It will be helpful for future users.